# Access LAN from behind a router

Tags: networking, router, lan

My router, a UniFi Security Gateway from Ubiquiti, is connected to a local network that provides internet connectivity via the WAN port. The LAN port on the device is my personal network to which my computer is connected.

Below is a diagram of the network to give you a visual:

[image: Network Diagram]

My two questions are:

1. If in a typical setup your LAN device can connect to IPs on the WAN (i.e, your computer can ping your neighbor's IP and 8.8.8.8), why can't my device connect to any devices in LAN 1 as pictured above? The router is connected directly to that network and can ping every device in LAN 1, but my device cannot- it does have internet access however.
2. How can I configure my router to allow my computer (or any device on LAN 2) to connect to LAN 1?

I know there are many questions on SU about connecting from the internet INTO a LAN through a router (use a VPN, port forward, etc), but I'm hoping to figure out how to do the opposite.

Thanks!

Comment: This is not a standard behavior for NAT gateway routers. I don't know if this is a standard behavior for your particular product, however. I don't think there's any way for anyone to answer this question without inspecting how you've got your router configured. Is it doing NAT? Does it have its firewall feature turned on? What firewall rules is it using?

Comment: Are you cascading the routers for port expansion or some other reason?  Are both routers identical models? (if not, you'll need to be more specific about which plugged in to which)  Are you running both devices with default settings or have you customized them? (if so, what have you customized)  These are just a few questions that come to mind... network configuration issues can get quite nit-picky re: your environment.